# Gazebo complains about default_robot_hw_sim

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I originally opened this in ros but it may be gazebo issue?

Gazebo complains about default_robot_hw_sim in hydro. BTW if I run the script that is mentioned it runs says successful but still get the same error.

```
pluginlib WARNING: In file /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control-2.3.3-0raring-20131021-0406/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS is deprecated, please use PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS instead. You can run the script 'plugin_macro_update' provided with pluginlib in your package source folder to automatically and recursively update legacy macros.  Base = base_class_type, Derived = derived_class_type
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5119/gazebo-complains-about-default_robot_hw_sim/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That's just a deprecation warning message. You can ignore it. I've submitted a gazebo_ros_control pull request that, among other things, eliminates the source of that message.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 247 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0